# Linux, Screen / nohup not working for background process

Tags: linux, ssh, display, nohup

I'm using a remove site (a mac if that makes a difference) to run some processes. The first time I sshed into it and set up the process using nohup / & before logging off. When I came back to see how it was doing I noticed that the process had been killed when I logged off.

So to try and get around this I used screen instead and detached myself before logging off. I then sshed back in to see if it was still running (which it was) so I logged off and left it. When I came back later that day I tried to reattach myself to the screen however it came back with the 'There is no screen to be resumed.' response. When I looked through my log file I noticed that the process had randomly died about 40 minutes after I'd logged off with no error. Of course all the  other windows I had open on the screen session were also gone.

I've tried numerous solutions, including keeping the ssh connection open and using KeepServerAlive in ssh_config to keep the connection alive. This time at some (seemingly random) point after the process has started it logs me off with a broken pipe. I've tried running a session in screen without the process to see if that was the issue but was met with the same issue as above.

Any thoughts / answers on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the process is being killed, rather than exiting prematurely itself?

Comment: No I'm not sure to be honest with you